# Select all children and its childrens

Tags: c#

From this data:

```
var item1 = new Item(1);
var item2 = new Item(2);
var item3 = new Item(3);
var item4 = new Item(4);
var item5 = new Item(5);
var item6 = new Item(6);
var item7 = new Item(7);
var item8 = new Item(8);

item1.Requirements = new List<Item>() { item2, item3 };
item2.Requirements = new List<Item>() { item4, item5 };
item5.Requirements = new List<Item>() { item6 };
item6.Requirements = new List<Item>() { item8 };
```

I want to get all `item1` childrens and childrens of childrens.

```
var items = item1.Requirements.SelectManyRecursive(x => x.Requirements).ToList();
```

I managed this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectManyRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    var result = source.SelectMany(selector);

    if (!result.Any())
    {
        return result;
    }
    return result.Concat(result.SelectManyRecursive(selector));
}
```

And I expected result:

```
item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item8
```

Unfortunelly it is missing `item2` and `item3`. I can solve this by:

```
var items = item1.Requirements.Concat(item1.Requirements.SelectManyRecursive(x => x.Requirements)).ToList();
```

But that looks ugly. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectChildren<T>(this T RootNode, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var firstLevelChildren = childSelector(RootNode);
    return firstLevelChildren.Concat(firstLevelChildren.SelectMany(c => SelectChildren(c, childSelector)));
}


var items = item1.SelectChildren(x => x.Requirements);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```